# php форма связи

Tags: php

происходит отправка формы..если все ок то

```
if($mail){
  header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
}
```

нужно прибавить параметр в url к  `('$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']')` с которой пришел пользователь , что то типо 'http://where_you_came_from.com?m=1' , что бы на той странице уже можно было проверить

```
if($_get && isset($_get['m'])){ 
    echo ($_get['m']) ? 'блок с сообщением об отправке письма' : 
    'блок с сообщением об ошибке отправки'.;
}'
```

Comment: [Explode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php), [Parse-url](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php), [Preg-split](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-split.php), [Str-split](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-split.php)

Answer (score 0):

все мега просто , нам нужно воспользоваться функцией explode() ,
 символ ? не встречается в url с которой пришел пользователь , а значит он преобразует значение в строку, которую можно запихнуть в переменную , а  затем просто к строке добавить все что нужно.

```
 $bits = explode('?',$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
                $redirect = $bits[0];
                header('Location: ' .$redirect. '?m=1');
```